# XCode 3.2 does not mark unit test assert failures in the editor

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, xcode3.2

I've been off in Java land for about a month or so and now, upon returning to XCode I feel lost. I've upgraded 1st to 3.1.2 then recently to 3.2 and also got a new Mac with Snow Leopard so I'm not exactly sure when the problem surfaced. I just know that I used to get little red bubbles in my unit test next to the failing asserts and that no longer seems to happen. Is there a way to restore this? I've been trying to use Apple's own SenTesting framework instead of GoogleTools for mac like I used to. Should I revert to Google Tools? Does anyone have an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kinda working now, but dramatically different than what I was used to. I'm not sure what the deal is/was. Unit testing has always seemed like a flaky unsupported thing in XCode.